# cannot use setFieldsValue of Ant Design Form of class component

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to use setFieldsValue to fill value in form. Although I initialized form.ref, I can't use this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue to set value to a field. I get this error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setFieldsValue' of null. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please add some more info or a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code. As I had this issue, this is cause the form ain't initialized yet. If you provide your code, people can see, and tell you a solution.